# overrideUserInterfaceStyle not working in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate, ios-darkmode

I'm building an iOS app with the newest version of Xcode.

If I set

```
overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

to a View Controller, it will get set to light mode, also if dark mode is enabled.

But If I put this code in AppDelegate like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    
    return true
}
```

it doesn't work.

There are no errors. The app simply is in light mode or dark mode depending on the mode the device is in.

Why doesn't `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` work in AppDelegate? Is it because I'm using a Tab Bar Controller for my app? I don't think so.

Comment: If you have a scene delegate, the app delegate has no window.

Answer (score -2):

It's too early to call `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` in AppDelegate, window is not yet created. You can use SceneDelegate `willConnectTo` function.